# Prevent iPhone from locking when connected to charger and app is running

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm writing an iPhone app. When the app is running and the iPhone is charging, there is no need to lock the iPhone. Is it possible to prevent the locking of the iPhone when the device is charging and my app is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subscribe to `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification` notification to get the moment when your iphone begins/stops to charge. Then in case iphone is charging you can set idleTimerDisabled property in UIApplication object to YES to prevent device to go to sleep:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(updateBatteryState:) 
                             name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:nil];


- (void) updateBatteryState:(NSNotification*)notification{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = 
         ([UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging);
}
```

P.S. If user decides to put device to sleep with sleep/wake button there's no way to prevent him of doing so

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible with current SDK.

EDIT: hmm, haven't got the question correctly from the first read - look on other replies for correct answer; my guess was, you were asking about if it possible to prevent appearance of the sync/charge screen when connecting device via usb or to the wall outlet